# Multiple Formatting Methods for MultiIndex Table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have created a pivot table with the below code. I have also included test data below.

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(table, 
                       values=['exposure'], 
                       index=['company_type', 'buyer_category'], 
                       columns=['loan_product'], 
                       aggfunc= [np.sum, len, lambda x: x.sum()/11589305], 
                       margins=True)
```

I need to format the dataframe so that the columns in level 0 have different formats.

I want to use  `"${:1,.0f}"` for the 'Sum' & 'Len' columns and I want to use `"{:.2f}%"` for the third column `(lambda x: x.sum()/11589305)`

I have done a lot of research and cannot find the correct method. The following was one of my attempts. It correctly seperated the relevent columnn but I could not simultaneosly apply a different formatting to the other columns.

```
portfolio_exposure_pivot = (portfolio_exposure_pivot.loc[idx[:, :], 'Sum']).applymap("${:1,.0f}".format)
```

This is a set of sample data for the problem.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({
    'exposure':[4500, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 6000, 8000], 
    'loan_product':['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'], 
    'buyer_category':['private', 'private', 'public', 'public', 'public', 'private', 'private'], 
    'company_type':['corporation', 'corporation', 'sole_prop', 'sole_prop', 'sole_prop', 'corporation', 'corporation']})
```

Comment: Uh... please add quotes to the strings so we don't have to do it ourselves.

Comment: Added them in !

Comment: OK, we're almost there. I just need to see what your expected output looks like. There's a lot of text here and I have ADHD :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'exposure':[4500, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 6000, 8000], 
    'loan_product':['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'], 
    'buyer_category':['private', 'private', 'public', 'public', 'public', 'private', 'private'], 
    'company_type':['corporation', 'corporation', 'sole_prop', 'sole_prop', 'sole_prop', 'corporation', 'corporation']})

pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, 
                       values=['exposure'], 
                       index=['company_type', 'buyer_category'], 
                       columns=['loan_product'], 
                       aggfunc= [np.sum, len, lambda x: x.sum()/11589305], 
                       margins=True)

a = pivot[['sum','len']].applymap('${:1,.0f}'.format)

b = pivot[['<lambda>']].applymap('{:.2f}%'.format)

print(pd.concat([a,b], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
                                 sum                        len         <lambda>              
                            exposure                   exposure         exposure              
loan_product                       A        B      All        A   B All        A      B    All
company_type buyer_category                                                                   
corporation  private         $14,500   $6,000  $20,500       $3  $1  $4    0.00%  0.00%  0.00%
sole_prop    public           $2,000   $4,000   $6,000       $1  $2  $3    0.00%  0.00%  0.00%
All                          $16,500  $10,000  $26,500       $4  $3  $7    0.00%  0.00%  0.00%
```